# Reording columns after column autogeneration in C#/Silverlight Program

Tags: c#, .net, sql, silverlight

I am creating a an application with c#, silverlight. I am trying to figure out how to reorder the columns in my datagrid after they are autogenerated.

I tried doing something like this:

```
    private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "taskName":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 0;
                    break;
                }
            case "overallPercentComplete":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 1;
                    break;
                }
            case "TDO_ID":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 2;
                    break;
                }
            case "WBS_ID":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 3;
                    break;
                }
            case "baseLineSD":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 4;
                    break;
                }
            case "baseLineEd":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 5;
                    break;
                }
            case "estimatedSD":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 6;
                    break;
                }
            case "estimatedED":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 7;
                    break;
                }
            case "IMS_Hours":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 8;
                    break;
                }
            case "ETC_Hours":
                {
                    e.Column.DisplayIndex = 9;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't exactly work correctly. For this datagrid, the order should be:
taskName, overallPercentComplete, TDO_ID, WBS_ID, baseLineSD, baseLineED, estimatedSD, estimatedED, IMS_Hours, ETC_Hours.

I thought by modifying the Column.DisplayIndex property that would set it up correctly.
However, when this code actually executes, the order is:
taskNme, baseLineEd, TDO_ID, WBS_ID, overallPercentComplete, baseLineSD, estimatedED, estimatedSD, ETC_Hours, IMS_Hours.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

* EDIT ***

```
  void dataGrid1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 6;
        dataGrid1.Columns[1].DisplayIndex = 7;
        dataGrid1.Columns[2].DisplayIndex = 8;
        dataGrid1.Columns[3].DisplayIndex = 9;
        dataGrid1.Columns[4].DisplayIndex = 4;
        dataGrid1.Columns[5].DisplayIndex = 5;
        dataGrid1.Columns[6].DisplayIndex = 3;
        dataGrid1.Columns[7].DisplayIndex = 2;
        dataGrid1.Columns[8].DisplayIndex = 0;
        dataGrid1.Columns[9].DisplayIndex = 1;
    }
```

Still nothing, but with the Loaded event handler, I get an error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Error Details:
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at camDashboard.Views.Details.dataGrid1_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Comment: I don't know, maybe it isn't possible. I also tried with a Loaded event. Still nothing. Posting Code above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this indeed seems to be impossible in Silverlight today.

Having produced a working solution using the AutoGeneratedColumns event in WPF, I have checked the Silverlight DataGrid source code with Reflector, and first of all, there is no AutoGeneratedColumns event, and second, they indeed sort the columns inside `GenerateColumns()` (the location your event handler is called from) using a fixed algorithm regardless of your display index settings.

*I can update this placeholder with the WPF solution if it's of any interest.*

Answer (score 1):

The way, that I understood, WPF renders data grid columns when `AutoGenerateColumns` is set as `True` is: If the structure is being generated against ClassA which inherits from ClassB, the order of generation is ClassA and then ClassB with the order of declaration of the the properties in ClassA and ClassB containing the data.

The way that I had designed my class is that the properties would be defined in order of functional significance and I would control the order with a custom attribute `SortIndexAttribute` defined on the properties as `[SortIndex(1)]` with index as any integer value.

So, I as well, faced a lot of challenge overcoming this.

The way I thought was that, with the defined sort index, I can re-arrange my properties accordingly and then set the `DisplayIndex` at run-time in the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of the `DataGridColumn`.

However, I face a new challenge. If the order of declaration of the properties and and the sort index don't match and while setting, if the sort index is greater than the column count throws an error. `DisplayIndex`, while setting, can be 0 or less than the column count (note: columns are generated and populated one at a time; also, when `DisplayIndex` is not set, it stores -1 which cannot be manually assigned)

I am yet to implement the below logic, but it might just work.
1. Create a sorted list of all the properties of ClassA (both native and inherited)
2. In the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event of the `DataGridColumn`, set the `DisplayIndex` of the first column to 0
3. Now, as per the order in my mapping, I will assign 0 or 1 for the new column w.r.t to the first one and so on..
4. If sort index is not available, I will just set it to the column count or skip altogether and let WPF handle it - NOT IMPLEMENTED YET

To explain #3 clearly, the order of generation of properties and sort index are as below:
Employee: Name(1), ID(0), Address(99), ZIPCODE(50)

WPF will generate the columns in the above order. So in the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, I will implement as below for my properties:

1. Name(1): Set `DisplayIndex = 0` (will insert at the first place)
2. ID(0): Set `DisplayIndex = 0` (should displace the existing at 0)
3. Address(99): Set `DisplayIndex = 2` (mark with column count or simply skip)
4. ZIPCODE(50): Set `DisplayIndex = 2` (should displace the existing at 0)

Below is my final code:

```
  private int SetDisplayIndex(string propName)
  {
    int result = -1;
    int curr = dictPropertySortIndexMap.GetValueFromKey[propName];
    int last = dictPropertySortIndexMap[nameSortLast];

    // For the first property in order, always set 0
    if (nameSortLast.IsBlank())
      result = 0;

    // For the property with lower index than sorted at first position
    else if (curr > dictColumnsSorted.Values.Max())
      result = dgrdUniversal.Columns.Count;

    // For the property with higher index than sorted at last position
    else if (curr < dictColumnsSorted.Values.Min())
      result = 0;

    else // For the property to be inserted between
      result = dictColumnsSorted[dictPropertySortIndexMap[
          dictPropertySortIndexMap._Where(
            p => dictColumnsSorted.Keys.Contains(p.Key) && p.Value > curr)                 ._Select(p => p.Value)._Min()]];

    dictColumnsSorted.Add(propName, result);
    nameSortLast = propName;

    return result;
  }
```

Please try this and leave your comments.

Thanks,
Rupak

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it's really possible.  See here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/144247.aspx

Comment: I have read that very same forum. Although, I am having a hard time believing that it isn't possible. It seems a little ridiculous that the program changes the orders of your tables, in favor of an alphabetical order, and not allowing you to rearrange them and put them in some sort of decent order.

Comment: If you know all the columns beforehand, why don't you just set them up yourself instead of using AutoGenerateColumns?

Comment: It looks like I will have to do that. It means creating a little bit of a workaround, but it doesn't look like I will have much choice. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got this working. Pretty much the only way I could figure this out was to not use AutoGenerating Columns and just define the columns myself in the XAML. Here is how I did that if anyone is interested.

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="392" Margin="32,360,36,0" Name="dataGrid3" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TDO1" Binding="{Binding Path=TDO_ID, Mode=OneWay}" Header="TDO_ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="taskName1" Binding="{Binding Path=taskName, Mode=OneWay}" Header="taskName" IsReadOnly="True" Width="304" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="weekName" Binding="{Binding Path=weekName, Mode=OneWay}" Header="weekName" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="scheduleVariance" Binding="{Binding Path=scheduleVariance, Mode=OneWay}" Header="SV (Days)" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="schedulePerformanceIndex" Binding="{Binding Path=schedulePerformanceIndex, Mode=OneWay}" Header="SPI" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ECD" Binding="{Binding Path=ECD, Mode=OneWay}" Header="ECD" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="percentComplete" Binding="{Binding Path=percentComplete, Mode=OneWay}" Header="% Complete" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="percentExpected" Binding="{Binding Path=percentExpected, Mode=OneWay}" Header="% Expected" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="WBS1" Binding="{Binding Path=WBS_ID, Mode=OneWay}" Header="WBS_ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

And I do apologize that its all jumbled up. Not quite sure how to fix that because the lines are just so long. Take care all.

Answer (score -1):

```
void autogen()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Employee", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()) + 1;

    }
    dr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    if (i <= 9)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "EID0" + i.ToString();
    }
    else if (i <= 99)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "EID" + i.ToString();
    }

}
```